# Echo out user information in the same table to their page base on their store information without echoing out the same information to another user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all I stored users in the same table and I created a page called welcome.php, where I want it to be echoing out user info from MySQL based on their entry.

Now when I created first user and echo it out to this welcome.php, it comes out from the table, and if I create another user info in the same table for it to echo out at the same welcome.php based on the user login info such as, if I create a user called John Fred etc and a user called Michael Kenneth etc.

So user John Fred comes out to the welcome.php with its information from the same table, and then user Michael Kenneth doesn't come to welcome.php when i sign with user Michael Kenneth instead it shows only user John Fred. I don't know where this error comes from; maybe from the login.php, or from welcome.php.

Here is my code echoing in welcome.php

```
<?php

$tnumber2 = "{$_SESSION['tnumber2']}"; 
//  Connect to the database

$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 


$sql="SELECT * FROM `$Tname` LIMIT 0, 25 ;"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>

<? echo $rows['tnumber2']; ?>
```

Another script for other user info which I store for another table:

```
<?php

//  Connect to the database
$tnumber2 = "{$_SESSION['tnumber2']}";

$db = mysql_connect("$Sname","$Uname","$Pname") or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db("$Dname") or die("Could not select the Database."); 


$sql="SELECT * FROM `$UPname` LIMIT 0, 25 ;"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row 
?>

<? echo $rows['pdate']; ?>

<?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

And here is my login.php in this case am using one input form:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
?>
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $tnumber2 = $_POST['user'];

    if ($tnumber2) {
            require("connect.php");

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tnumber2='$tnumber2'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrows == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                $id = $row['id'];
                $tnumber2 = $row['tnumber2'];

                if ($tnumber2 == $tnumber2) {   
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
                        $_SESSION['tnumber2'] = $tnumber2;

                        header("Location: welcome.php");
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        include "error.php";


    }
}
?>
```

I have tried all I can on this, maybe I might be a fool to think that such thing is possible but I am not a PHP professional, just a learner, please any help will be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Is the redirect working in your login.php? What is the `ob_start` for in that script? I am not sure you need it.

Comment: Also, I suspect you have a SQL injection in here - at least you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent users from injecting their own SQL in your database queries.

Comment: Lastly, it is rather important to split complex question descriptions up into paragraphs, otherwise it will be nearly unreadable for people helping you. See my edit: all you need to do is to group sentences into groups of three or four, and then add in two carriage return characters.

Comment: @halfer the ob_start, is for the header location to start the header location

Comment: Yeah, so you don't need the `ob_start` at all, then. As I say, your first task is to work out if your redirect is being triggered at all - and it needs an `exit` after it, too.

Comment: yes it is redirect to the page welcome.php,

Comment: In your first script you read `$tnumber2` from the session, but don't make subsequent use of it.

Comment: how do i make subsequent use of it

Comment: Depends what you are trying to do. What do you want to happen in welcome.php?

Comment: I want to get variables for first users information to the welcome.php leaving the second user ignored until the second user signs in to see its information

Comment: I want to be able to separate two users information in the same table and allow it to appear once they enters their login details, such as when first enters its login details it redirect user to welcome.php and echo the first user's information only and not the second user information just the first user information, and when the second user enters its login details it redirect again to welcome.php and echo the second user's information only without add with the first user's info

Comment: That seems like an extremely long way of saying you want each user to see only their own information in welcome.php?

Comment: how is it possible can you explain?

Comment: Hang on, please confirm if I have understood your purpose correctly first.

Comment: how can i do this is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: I'll ask once more: **do you want each user to see just their own information in welcome.php**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the session has indeed stored the data of the logged-in user, you need to change "welcome.php" so it reads the correct user with a `WHERE` clause:

```
<?php

// Retrieve the ID of the user (and untaint it too)
$id = (int) $_SESSION['id']; 

//  Connect to the database (I've removed the unnecessary quotes)
$db = mysql_connect($Sname, $Uname, $Pname) or die("Could not connect to the Database."); 
$select = mysql_select_db($Dname) or die("Could not select the Database."); 

// Here is the query from the users table, we're selecting one user here
$sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id;"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);

?>

<!-- Let's see what is in rows now, should be just one record -->
<?php print_r($rows) ?>
```

I would advise that you try to understand each part of the code above, and indeed the same for the code you have - don't just copy-and-paste without knowing what each bit does. If you get stuck on something, don't be afraid to look it up in the manual!

I've used `print_r` to just dump the row result - you can use the contents of that to determine what columns and other data you wish to extract out of it. After you have done that, the `print_r` can be removed.

Bear in mind that your login is not testing for password correctness - it only checks that someone has entered a particular username in login.php. If you want users to log on with a username and password, that needs to be designed and implemented as well. There are many questions on this site with best-practice techniques on how to do that, if that's of interest to you.

It has, incidentally, been rather difficult to understand what you are doing. I don't think this is a problem with your English, which seems fine to me. Rather, it's worth remembering to write in short sentences (no more than 20 words, say) and short paragraphs (no more than 4 or 5 sentences). And keep your descriptions as short as you can - it makes the difference between people helping you and their deciding they don't understand what you are trying to do. I expect this advice would be just as relevant in your native language as well!

Also, remember to add as much useful information to a question as you can, and if people ask for clarification, make sure you answer all their questions. Remember that people here are volunteers, and you need to make their job as easy as possible.

Comment: excuse me i want to know why you using the id for does the id replace tnumber2 in my own code?

Comment: haven't try it out since then was busy just came back now

Comment: No worries. So, by `id` I meant the primary key of the user. If `tnumber` is the primary key in your code, use that - I just used `id` as this is often used as a PK. What is the purpose of these columns in your table?

Comment: no tnumber isn't the primary key, is what represent the username in the login form

Comment: the id you use it isn't the user input?

Comment: am sorry to ask course i don't know where i will be making mistake the purpose of the columns is the users information's such as address, dates,

Comment: I've just noticed `($tnumber2 == $tnumber2)` in your code - this will _always_ return true, and is probably not what you intended. If you compare any number/string variable against itself, it will return true.

Comment: You can use `tnumber` from the session then, if this represents the username - that should be unique as well.

Comment: Final thought - it seems to me you are just getting started with PHP/MySQL. That's okay, but it may pay off to get a book to study with this stuff, before diving into building your own applications. You may be taking too much on at present, and need to solidify what you already know with more learning. Just a thought.

Comment: what is the book called?

Comment: I don't have a particular one in mind, but [there are plenty of suggestions here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+mysql+book+recommendation).

Comment: ok i have fix for each user to see only their information's, and is working, but remember i told you that i have two tables in welcome.php, now i fix the first table but the first table prevent the second table not to show up the information on it how do i separate both tables.

Comment: i have this the first: $sql="SELECT * FROM `$Tname` WHERE `id` = $id;"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result); and this the second: $sql="SELECT * FROM `$UPname` WHERE `id` = $id;"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); which echos with new html table lines

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51301/discussion-between-halfer-and-wilson)

Comment: i have wrote to you but no response

Comment: +1 A solution plus a descriptive text to boot; couldn't ask for better. My hands would've probably cramped up after "Bear in mind..." ;-)